# Selenium Node is not replying to /status HTTP-Request

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid, selenium-hub

so I got a selenium hub and some nodes.
Two Windows 10 VM's (`A` and `B`) on an ESXi.

`B` was cloned from `A`, so they are identical in their
configuration except IP and hostname.
`A` has a node, which works fine.
`B` has a node, but the hub cannot get the status of it,
so I first used a fixed port and restartet the node
but I cannot get the status via `http://win10-b:16050/status`.

I allowed Java to access through firewall and even disabled
both firewalls (hub and node) briefly, to no avail.

This is the node:

```
C:/>%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -port 16050 -host %USERDOMAIN% -hub http://win-hub:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=chrome,maxInstances=3,platform=WINDOWS

13:47:20.850 INFO [GridLauncherV3.parse] - Selenium server version: 3.141.59, revision: e82be7d358
13:47:21.024 INFO [GridLauncherV3.lambda$buildLaunchers$7] - Launching a Selenium Grid node on port 16050
2019-07-26 13:47:21.605:INFO::main: Logging initialized @1140ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
13:47:22.023 INFO [WebDriverServlet.<init>] - Initialising WebDriverServlet
13:47:32.168 INFO [SeleniumServer.boot] - Selenium Server is up and running on port 16050
13:47:32.169 INFO [GridLauncherV3.lambda$buildLaunchers$7] - Selenium Grid node is up and ready to register to the hub
13:47:32.229 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote$1.run] - Starting auto registration thread. Will try to register every 5000 ms.
13:47:32.860 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote.registerToHub] - Registering the node to the hub: http://win-hub:4444/grid/register
13:47:32.986 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote.registerToHub] - The node is registered to the hub and ready to use
```

This is the hub, desperatly trying to keep the connection:

```
13:56:07.821 INFO [DefaultGridRegistry.add] - Registered a node http://win-b:16050
13:56:19.854 INFO [DefaultRemoteProxy.onEvent] - Marking the node http://win-b:16050 as down: cannot reach the node for 2 tries
13:57:37.878 INFO [DefaultRemoteProxy.onEvent] - Unregistering the node http://win-b:16050 because it's been down for 78024 milliseconds
13:57:37.883 WARN [DefaultGridRegistry.removeIfPresent] - Cleaning up stale test sessions on the unregistered node http://win-b:16050
```

Any hint what I might be missing here, from 10 nodes in total, this is the only one that has issues (others except `A` are Windows 7 though).